# Sources to get source codes for sparse matrix solvers (non-symmetric matrix)

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix

For an implicit scheme I want to solve system $Ax=B$, where $A$ is a non-symmetric square matrix. I want source codes of large sparse matrix solvers (e.g. LU-SGS) to use in my code which is in C language. I have tried preconditioned GMRES code from [this site](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/mgmres/mgmres.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFIdnCp_e8EVq5oZW-RGoD1jEfBBA) but its getting slow and takes huge amount of memory(sometimes program is getting "killed" automatically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) and [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/). They have tons of different sparse solvers available.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say how big your system of equations is. But if you are interested in trying direct sparse solvers, here are links to two for non-symmetric systems that are known to be of high quality and are written in C.

[SuiteSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/)
[SuperLU](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/)

Comment: This link is very useful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend on [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). You can also look at [taucs](http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/).